# jQuery.ajax() error with textStatus=error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

The `jQuery.ajax()` function I use works correctly most of the time. However sometimes it is not returning any data. Instead the `error()` function is called.

```
$.ajax({

  [...]

  , error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

I can see in there that in those cases `textStatus` is `'error'` and `errorThrown` is `''` (empty).

The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) just lists the possible values of `textStatus` (`"timeout"`, `"error"`, `"abort"`, and `"parsererror"`). However it does not describe, what `'error'` means.

`jqXHR` returns an object but it does not seam to reveal any additional insights.

How can I investigate what the source to this issue is?

Comment: What do you get if you do `console.log(jqXHR.status)` ?

Comment: This is empty as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out it happens, whenever Reload is pressed in the browser, while the ajax request was still running.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15141116/351893) helped me implement a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use fiddler to monitor the request and analyze what you are getting in response.

Another thing to try is to compose your ajax request in fiddler composer. This way you can figure out whether your are passing all required headers or not.

You will find more details in fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

As KidA said in the comment try this:

```
console.log(jqXHR.status);
```

Also, just make sure you are pulling from the right destination (url, listname, etc.) along with the proper data type pull (POST, GET, UPDATE, DELETE, etc.)