# Error from AJAX Call, but no way to know what type of error it is

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this AJAX call within my HTML code , but the code runs the error attribute directly , gives the textStatus as "error" with no description of what kind of error it is.

Also , I checked that if the "Data" attribute had any issues. I found none.

I am not sure what is going on? Please help!

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#SendValues").click(function(){

 var street_number_new = $("#street_number").val();
 var route_new = $("#route").val();
 var locality_new = $("#locality").val();
 var admin_area_new = $("#administrative_area_level_1").val();
 var postal_code_new = $("#postal_code").val();
 var country_new = $("#country").val();
 var AddressFields = new Array();
  AddressFields[0]= street_number_new
  AddressFields[1]= route_new
  AddressFields[2]= locality_new;
  AddressFields[3]= admin_area_new ;
  AddressFields[4]= postal_code_new ;
  AddressFields[5]= country_new;
  alert("The values stored are"+AddressFields);

  $.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:'https://forms.na1.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=603&deploy=1&compid=TSTDRV1354957&h=d6eda18a4f37d2a41d2c',
data: AddressFields ,
success: function(data){
alert("Values went through "+ AddressFields);
  },

  error: function(){

    alert("Values did not go through");
  },
complete: function(response, textStatus) {
return alert("Hey: " + textStatus);
}
});
});
```

Comment: show error message

Comment: Have you printed all error details? `error: function(xhr, status, error) { console.log(status, error); }`

Comment: @ihemant360 : The error message is "Hey: error"

Comment: @eisbehr : No , i printed the textStatus only, let me try that

Comment: Check the return http status code inspecting your browser. It is in the network section.

Comment: check your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807572/jquery-ajax-error-handling-to-ignore-aborted/15141116#15141116

Comment: @eisbehr I am still getting the same error message which is "error"

Comment: I've posted a answer @Bharath. Maybe check this. That is my currently only idea. Everything else looks fine here.

Comment: I checked , it did not work @eisbehr